# Многопоточное vs асинхронное программирование

Tags: c#, .net, многопоточность, асинхронность

Хотелось бы узнать разницу между этими подходами.
Разве асинхронное программирование не подразумевает из себя уже многопоточность, ведь Task где-то там по любому выполняется в отдельном потоке ?

В каких случаях нужно прибегать к многопоточному, а в каких к асинхронному программированию ?

И еще ко всему этому есть параллельное программирование, которая тоже вносит путаницу для меня. В чем её отличие ?

Comment: Слишком много вопросов каждый из которых и так потребует большой ответ. Можно ограничится первым абзацем, остальное лучше заменить примером.

Comment: Возможный [хороший дубликат](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/416086/10105).

Comment: @VladD помнил этот ответ, но не смог найти. Его бы вот сюда переместить :). А то к оригинальному вопросу он имеет мало отношения, а здесь в самый раз пригодился бы.

Comment: @andreycha: Ага, я тоже дооооолго искал :) Может, попросить модератора? Спрошу в чате. // [Спросил](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/23731904#23731904).

Comment: _"Task где-то там по любому выполняется в отдельном потоке"_ -- работой Task'ов управляет System.Threading.Tasks.TaskScheduler и его наследники. Task'и выполняются в потоках (Thread) -- их несколько. Они обратывают Task'и по очереди.

Comment: @Stack: А как же в том случае если код (который мы запускаем в задаче) работает с некоторыми переменными? Т.е. у нас есть основной поток, в котором есть переменная, и мы запустим несколько задач, которые с этой переменной работают (вместе с основным потоком читают и модифицируют её). В многопоточном программировании надо заботиться о таких вещах (например, использовать блокировку lock). Следует ли заботиться об аналогичных ситуациях в задачах? Я так понял, из всех пояснений в этом вопросе, что нет. Значит, об этих вещах заботится TaskScheduler?

Answer (score 186, accepted):

Попробую собрать воедино все, что дали уже в комментариях.

Есть несколько разных понятий, связанных с областью параллельных вычислений.

- Конкурентное исполнение (concurrency)
- Параллельное исполнение (parallel execution)
- Многопоточное исполнение (multithreading)
- Асинхронное исполнение (asynchrony)

Каждый из этих терминов строго определен и имеет четкое значение.

## Конкурентность (concurrency)

Конкурентность (*) (concurrency) - это наиболее общий термин, который говорит, что одновременно выполняется более одной задачи. Например, вы можете одновременно смотреть телевизор и комментить фоточки в фейсбуке. Винда, даже 95-я могла (**) одновременно играть музыку и показывать фотки.

(*) К сожалению, вменяемого русскоязычного термина я не знаю. Википедия говорит, что concurrent computing - это параллельные вычисления, но как тогда будет parallel computing по русски?

(**) Да, вспоминается анекдот про Билла Гейтса и многозадачность винды, но, *теоретически* винда могла делать несколько дел одновременно. Хотя и не любых.

Конкурентное исполнение - это самый общий термин, который не говорит о том, каким образом эта конкурентность будет получена: путем приостановки некоторых вычислительных элементов и их переключение на другую задачу, путем действительно одновременного исполнения, путем делегации работы другим устройствам или еще как-то. Это не важно.

*Конкурентное исполнение* говорит о том, что за определенный промежуток времени будет решена более, чем одна задача. Точка.

## Параллельное исполнение

Параллельное исполнение (parallel computing) подразумевает наличие более одного вычислительного устройства (например, процессора), которые будут *одновременно* выполнять несколько задач.

Параллельное исполнение - это строгое подмножество конкурентного исполнения. Это значит, что на компьютере с одним процессором параллельное программирование - невозможно;)

## Многопоточность

Многопоточность - это один из способов реализации конкурентного исполнения путем выделения абстракции "рабочего потока" (worker thread).

Потоки "абстрагируют" от пользователя низкоуровневые детали и позволяют выполнять более чем одну работу "параллельно". Операционная система, среда исполнения или библиотека прячет подробности того, будет многопоточное исполнение конкурентным (когда потоков больше чем физических процессоров), или параллельным (когда число потоков меньше или равно числу процессоров и несколько задач физически выполняются одновременно).

## Асинхронное исполнение

Асинхронность (asynchrony) подразумевает, что операция может быть выполнена кем-то на стороне: удаленным веб-узлом, сервером или другим устройством за пределами текущего вычислительного устройства.

Основное свойство таких операций в том, что начало такой операции требует значительно меньшего времени, чем основная работа. Что позволяет выполнять множество асинхронных операций одновременно даже на устройстве с небольшим числом вычислительных устройств.

## CPU-bound и IO-Bound операции

Еще один важный момент, с точки зрения разработчика - разница между CPU-bound и IO-bound операциями. CPU-Bound операции нагружают вычислительные мощности текущего устройства, а IO-Bound позволяют выполнить задачу вне текущей железки.

Разница важна тем, что число одновременных операций зависит от того, к какой категории они относятся. Вполне нормально запустить параллельно сотни IO-Bound операций, и надеяться, что хватит ресурсов обработать все результаты. Запускать же параллельно слишком большое число CPU-bound операций (больше, чем число вычислительных устройств) бессмысленно.

---

Возвращаясь к исходному вопросу: нет смысла выполнять в 1000 потоков метод `Calc`, если он является CPU-Intensive (нагружает центральный процессор), поскольку это приведет к падению общей эффективности вычислений. ОС-ке придется переключать несколько доступных ядер для обслуживания сотен потоков. А этот процесс не является дешевым.

Самым простым и эффективным способом решения CPU-Intensive задачи, заключается в использовании идиомы Fork-Join: задачу (например, входные данные) нужно разбить на определенное число подзадач, которые можно выполнить параллельно. Каждая подзадача должна быть независимой и не обращаться к разделяемым переменным/памяти. Затем, нужно собрать промежуточные результаты и объединить их.

Именно на этом принципе основан PLINQ. О чем можно почитать тут: [Джозеф Албахари. Параллельное программирование](http://sergeyteplyakov.blogspot.com/2010/09/51.html).

Выглядит это очень интересно:

```
IEnumerable<Data> yourData = GetYourData();
var result = yourData.AsParallel() // начинаем обрабатывать параллельно
  .Select(d => ComputeMD5(d)) // Вычисляем параллельно
  .Where(md5 => IsValid(md5))
  .ToArray(); // Возврвщаемся к синхронной модели
```

В этом случае, число потоков будет контролироваться библиотечным кодом в недрах CLR/TPL и метод `ComputeMD5` будет вызван параллельно N-раз на компьютере с N-процессорами (ядрами).

Comment: concurrency = одновременность?

Comment: А я воспринимал concurrency больше как наличие задач, которые независят друг от друга (конкурирующие задачи на обработку в твоей системе) и могут быть обработаны в любом порядке/кусочками или паралельно.

Comment: По поводу thread - мне очень даже нравится. А то частенько слышу про то что необходимы потоки для того, что бы использовать эффективно многоядерность и прочее. Но не думаю, что стоит употреблять термин "рабочий поток". Просто поток исполнения, который позволяет проще писать. Ведь, не обязательно применять разделение на роли.

Comment: Ещё девять плюсов этому ответу и ещё три минуса вопросу — и будет первый реверс. :)

Comment: @ony: и ты тут!
По поводу первого коммента: слово concurrency подразумевает "борьбу", но вот вопрос: если система выполняет две задачи в один момент времени можно считать ее конкурентной?

Comment: @SergeyTeplyakov, до момента выполнения задачи конкурируют так как они могут обе использовать оба вычислительных устройства и система делает выбор какую задачу выполнять на каком устройстве на каких-то своих предпочтениях. Если бы каждая задача могла исполнятся только на своём устройстве, то это уже не конкурирующие задачи (в моём понимании) и термин concurrency на них не распростроняется.

Comment: Действительно хороший ответ. Для большей полноты можно было бы еще кратко рассказать о конвейеризации (pipeline и SIMD) и рассмотреть fine-grained и coarse-grained parallelism.

Comment: Слово «Concurrency» переводится на русский язык как «Единовременный». И «Параллельный» – это также «Единовременный». Слово «Concurrent» переводится на русский язык как «Соперник» – так что вы правы насчёт борьбы. Пожалуйста, исправьте ваш ответ в соответствии с этими переводами, поскольку мы находимся на русскоязычной странице и в правилах написано, что общение должно быть на русском языке.

Comment: @Bharata Со всем уважением, но я не буду исправлять ответ в соответствии с комментариями. И если кто-то другой попробует изменить его на указанные переводы, я буду против. Проблема в том, что "правильных" переводов подобных терминов не существует. Точнее, это наше с вами решение, какое использовать. Я, например, не слышал чтобы кто-то использовал указанные термины в разговоре, статьях или книгах. Поэтому я не считаю их приемлемыми.

Answer (score 64):

Вам нужно выкопать во дворе бассейн.

- Вы взяли лопату и копаете. Это однопоточная работа
- Вы пригласили друга Васю и копаете вместе, периодически задевая друг-друга лопатами. Это многопоточная работа
- Пока вы копаете бассейн, Вася копает канаву под водопровод. Никто никому не мешает. Это распараллеливание
- Вы пригласили бригаду землекопов, а сами с Васей пошли пить пиво. Когда бригада все сделает, к вам придут за деньгами. Это асинхронная работа.

Количество лопат в хозяйстве - это количество ядер в системе

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, правильно ли я понял, что многопоточная и асинхронная работы являются частными случаями параллельного программирования? В этом руководстве .NET https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/parallel-processing-and-concurrency написано про параллельное следующее: "без необходимости работать непосредственно с потоками или пулом потоков", значит работа с потоками частный случай параллельного? А вот на счет асинхронного не совсем понятно.

Comment: @WebFR **Многопоточность** - это частный случай параллельного программирования, точнее, квази-параллельного, поскольку потоки переключаются так быстро, что создаётся иллюзию их параллельности. **Асинхронность** - это способ организации кода, при котором во время выполнения "долгой" задачи может выполняться ещё что-то другое полезное. Асинхронность может достигаться разными технологиями, в том числе и многопоточностью. Подробнее здесь: https://youtu.be/0E50FVd5PGQ

Answer (score 30):

**Многопоточное программирование** подразумевает, что код приложения выполняется в разных потоках. Например, есть главный поток UI, и несколько рабочих потоков, которые выполняют тяжелые вычисления, результаты которых затем выводятся на UI.

**Асинхронное программирование** подразумевает инициацию некоторой операцию, об окончании которой главный поток узнает спустя некоторое время. Обычно это применяется для работы с системой ввода-вывода: диски, сеть и т.д. При этом, если это все сделано правильно, [никакого потока нет](http://habrahabr.ru/post/216659/). Также часто под выражением "выполнить асинхронно" подразумевают, что выполнение некоторого кода будет произведено не в текущем потоке, а в соседнем, при этом текущий поток не будет заблокирован. Но мой взгляд, это не совсем корректно.

**Параллельное программирование** подразумевает разбиение одной задачи на независимые подзадачи, которые можно рассчитать параллельно, а затем объединить результаты. Один из примеров -- это [map-reduce](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce). Это частный случай многопоточного программирования.

Comment: Ам.. я так понял доклад на .NEXT 2014 msc "Async/await: собираем грабли" это Ваш доклад? :-)

Comment: @AntonKomyshan точно :).

Comment: Не знаю, как в терминологии шарпа, а вообще-то *многопоточное* это **частный случай**  *параллельного* программирования.

Answer (score 11):

1. Многопоточная работа - работа нескольких потоков. При этом не факт, что все потоки будут активны. Возможно, что работает один поток, а другой спит. Когда первый поток закончил работу, он может разбудить второй, а сам заснуть
2. Распараллеливание - разбиение одной задачи на независимые подзадачи и выполнение этих подзадач одновременно разными потоками. Пример: вычисление среднего значения двумерного массива. Каждый поток может посчитать сумму своей строки, а потом все это объединить
3. Асинхронная работа - когда мы ставим какую-то задачу, но не ждем ответа, а продолжаем делать свою работу. А когда будет готов ответ - нас уведомят. Пример: попросить секретаря сварить кофе. Мы не ждем этого кофе и занимаемся своими делами, а когда кофе будет готов - нам его принесут.

Количество ядер процессора определяет только сколько потоков могут одновременно быть в активном состоянии

Answer (score 1):

Прежде всего стоит отметить, что **многопоточность** - это всего лишь один из вариатов (способов, методов) получения **асинхронности** (асинхронного кода).

***Асинхронность - это техника, которая позволяет вашей программе запустить потенциально длительную задачу и по-прежнему иметь возможность реагировать на другие события во время выполнения этой задачи, вместо того, чтобы ждать, пока эта задача завершится***. https://it4each.com/blog/threading-multiprocessing-i-asyncio-v-python/

В Python есть 3 наиболее популярных способа сделать код асинхронным: пакеты **threading**, **multiprocessing** и **asyncio**. (*Очень подробно об этом рассказано здесь*: https://youtu.be/0E50FVd5PGQ).

Если же совсем коротко, то все 3 способа позволяют позволяют "запараллелить" выполнение кода. Но слово "параллелизм" в английском языке имеет 2 значения: **parallelism** (реальный параллелизм) и **concurrency** (квази-парраллелизм, часто ошибочно переводимый как "конкурентность").

#### *multiprocessing (parallelism) - это несколько процессов*

Из трёх перечисленных споособов асинхронности только  **multiprocessing** физически запускает несколько самостоятельных процессов на разных ядрах процессора, что делает выполнение программы действительно параллельным (**parallelism**).

Два других (**threading** и **asyncio**) - это квази-параллельное (**concurrency**) выполнение кода, когда идёт только один процесс, но переключение между разными участками кода происходит настолько быстро, что стороннему наблюдателю кажется, что эти части кода выполняются параллельно.

#### *threading (concurrency) - это один процесс и несколько потоков*

Разница только в том, что в **threading** (потоки) преключения происходят через равные промежутки времени и делает это операционная система, поэтому исходный код практически не меняется.

#### *asyncio  (concurrency) - это один процесс и один поток*

В **asyncio**, в отличии от **threading**, точки переключения указывает программист, поэтому в результате итоговый код довольно-таки значительно отличается от исходного.
[image: Три способа асинхронности]