# Вызов асинхронных методов внутри цикла

Tags: c#, async-await

Насколько я понимаю, вызов асинхронного метода внутри цикла с использованием ключевого слова `await` - совершенно бессмысленно, поскольку цикл продолжит выполняться только после выполнения этого метода.
По этой причине, два нижеследующих варианта с синхронным и асинхронным методом совершенно идентичны:

1.

```
while (true)
{
    var context = listener.GetContext();
    Task.run(() => HandleContext(context));
}
```

2.

```
while (true)
{
    var context = await listener.GetContextAsins();
    Task.run(() => HandleContext(context));
}
```

Таким образом, это делается как-то иначе. Возможно следует просто обернуть асинхронный вызов в другой метод, который уже и вызывать в цикле:

```
private async void GetContextAsync()
{
    var context = await listener.GetContextAsins();
    Task.run(() => HandleContext(context));
}
```

И в цикле:

```
while(true)
    GetContextAsync();
```

Или, может быть, правильнее это делать так:

```
while(true)
    listener.GetContextAsync().ContinueWith(...);
```

Пожалуйста, Поправьте меня, если я не прав, и покажите как делать правильно.

Comment: Варианты 1 и 2 вовсе не идентичны. Вариант 2 не тратит поток на то, чтобы ждать получения контекста.

Comment: @PetSerAl но ведь он заблокирует текущий поток? Цикл ведь не перейдет к следующей итерации?

Comment: @КонстантинГалиахметов, цикл не перейдет к след операции, но поток не будет заблокирован, он вернется в пул. Наверное вы путаете многопоточное и асинхронное программирование

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/416086/10105

Comment: @koks_rs Насчет блокировки потока я сглупил. Но тут меня главным образом интересует вопрос: как правильно вызвать в цикле асинхронный метод много раз?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Давайте посмотрим, что вам реально нужно. Вам нужно получить новое обращение (контекст), запустить его асинхронно на длительную обработку, и не дожидаясь окончания обработки ожидать прихода нового контекста, правильно?

```
ожидание -----> пришёл контекст -> ожидание -----------> пришёл новый контекст -> ожидание --
                     \                                       \
                      \                                       \
                   обрабатываем контекст -------------------------> закончили
                                                                \
                                                           обрабатываем новый контекст ----->
```

Этой схеме соответствует как первый, так и второй цикл. По поводу разницы между первым и вторым вариантом, как уже многие говорили, она лишь в том, что второй вариант не занимает потока на время ожидания. В остальном они выполняются одинаково. Второй вариант предпочтительнее, т. к. занимать поток безделием — нехорошо.

А вот третий вариант с `async void`, судя по всему, неправильный: `async void` означает, что содержимое метода запустится, и никто не будет дожидаться его результата. То есть итерации цикла будут бежать одна за другой, не дожидаясь даже окончания получения контекста. В результате у вас будет параллельно висеть очень много незавершённых `await listener.GetContextAsync();`. Вариант с `listener.GetContextAsync().ContinueWith(...);` точно так же порождает огромное число параллельных задач ожидания получения контекста.

Эти варианты соответствуют такой диаграмме:

```
ожидание -----> пришёл контекст
                    \
                     \
                   обрабатываем контекст
 ожидание -----> ?
  ожидание -----> ?
   ожидание -----> ?
    ожидание -----> ?
     ожидание -----> ?
      .
       .
        .
```

Вы видите, что одновременно происходит много ожиданий, это явно не то, что вам нужно.

Comment: Спасибо. Я именно вознамерился создать  множество незавершённых await listener.GetContextAsync(); исходя из предположения, видимо абсолютно неверного, что это как-то положительно может сказаться на производительности сервера. в конечном итоге предполагалось, что их создастся ограниченное количество, а не бесконечное как в примере. Буду благодарен если вы окончательно развеете это мое заблуждение

Comment: @КонстантинГалиахметов: Если речь идёт о сервере, то да, вызовы `GetContext`/`GetContextAsync` должны в любом случае быть последовательны. Параллельные вызовы, если я не ошибаюсь, не допускаются. // Пожалуйста!