# DbSet<T>.Add() vs DbSet<T>.AddAsync()

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, асинхронность, entity-framework-core

Есть отличная [статья-ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/416086/14935), которую наверное можно как некий справочник использовать когда необходимо освежить некоторые моменты в понимании параллельных вычислений. В этой статье касаемо асинхронного программирования, говорится

> Асинхронность (asynchrony) подразумевает, что операция может быть
>   выполнена кем-то на стороне...

и исходя из этого я могу понять разницу между `DbSet<T>.Save()` и `DbSet<T>.SaveAsync()`, а именно: когда сохранение у нас происходит во внешний источник (к примеру, база данных), где необходимо ожидать ответ и время этого ожидания не зависит от нашего кода, то предпочтительнее использовать асинхронный вариант этого метода, чтобы отпустить поток на другие нужды, а потом когда придет ответ продолжить работу с ответом уже этим или другим потоком.

**А что на счет асинхронного варианта `AddAsync()`, зачем-то он нужен, зачем ожидать ответ, разве добавление не происходит в памяти или я какой-то частный случай не знаю?**

Comment: Пробовали читать доки? This method is async only to allow special value generators, such as the one used by 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.SequenceHiLo', to access the database asynchronously. For all other cases the non async method should be used.

Comment: @tym32167 оформите ответом, пожалуйста.

Comment: скопипастил как ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласно [докам](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbset-1.addasync?view=efcore-2.0)

> This method is async only to allow special value generators, such as the one used by 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.SequenceHiLo', to access the database asynchronously. For all other cases the non async method should be used.

Comment: Да, документацию я конечно же читал и после твоего ответа более детально попытался вникнуть в суть. Но все равно не понимаю. К примеру, я так понимаю одно из преимуществ использование этого варианта Add это возможность самому генерировать ключи, что нам редко но все же не хватает, верно?

Comment: @adamshakhabov я сам не спец в этом, но, насколько я понял из гугла - есть способ генерирования ключа на клиенте, который иногда может для этого обратиться на сервер за новой инфой для генерации ключей. Иногда - когда текущий пул ключей кончится, чтобы спросить где начинается следующий пул ключей.  Вот из за запроса на сервер, я думаю, они добавили асинхронный вариант вставки. Подробнее [тут](http://www.talkingdotnet.com/use-hilo-to-generate-keys-with-entity-framework-core/) или [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/282099/whats-the-hi-lo-algorithm).