# Не работает асинхронный вызов метода C#

Tags: c#, асинхронность

Имеется метод, который внутри себя запускает дважды другой метод, но второй раз асинхронно. И вот внутри Task не срабатывает SaveToDB().. Подскажите, пожалуйста в чём моя ошибка

```
public IEnumerable<UserFeedPrerender> GetFeedPrerenders(int userId, FilterPaging paging)
    {
        var feedPrerenders = PreRenderFeed(userId, paging);

        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            var fullPrerenders = PreRenderFeed(userId, null);
            SaveToDB(fullPrerenders, userId);
        });

        return feedPrerenders;
    }


 public async void SaveToDB(IEnumerable<UserFeedPrerender> userFeedPrerenderElements, int userId)
    {
        await Task.Run(() => SaveSelectedElementsToDB(userFeedPrerenderElements, userId));
    }
```

Comment: Ну ошибка в том, что вы не дожидаетесь выполнения таска и теряете его.

Comment: @iluxa1810, я так понимаю нужно заменить возвращаемый тип с void на Task?

Comment: для начала да. Тем не менее, проблема останется.

Comment: @iluxa1810, будьте добры - подскажите как исправить её полностью

Comment: Попробуй, вместо IEnumerable время Task<T>, поставь модификатор async и через await дождись выполнения таска.

Comment: @iluxa1810, Работает, но тогда у меня return срабатывает только после того, как выполняется Task. А я хотел бы чтоб этот Task в фоне работал

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предположу, что вам надо что то вроде этого

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<UserFeedPrerender>> GetFeedPrerenders(int userId, FilterPaging paging)
{
    var feedPrerenders = PreRenderFeed(userId, paging);
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        var fullPrerenders = PreRenderFeed(userId, null);
        SaveSelectedElementsToDB(fullPrerenders, userId);
    });
    return feedPrerenders;
}
```

Вариант без асинхронного ожидания (в случае, если вас не волнует ни статус выполнения задачи, ни потенциально возникающие исключения в ней)

```
public IEnumerable<UserFeedPrerender> GetFeedPrerenders(int userId, FilterPaging paging)
{
    var feedPrerenders = PreRenderFeed(userId, paging);
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        var fullPrerenders = PreRenderFeed(userId, null);
        SaveSelectedElementsToDB(fullPrerenders, userId);
    });
    return feedPrerenders;
}
```

Comment: Тогда ведь не надо асинхронно SaveToDB() вызывать

Comment: @RomanIeromenko у меня вообще нет метода `SaveToDB()`

Comment: Да, согласен, был у него

Comment: Работает, но тогда у меня return срабатывает только после того, как выполняется Task. А я хотел бы чтоб этот Task в фоне работал

Comment: Асинхронность от многопоточности отличается почитай https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/445768/%D0%9C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-vs-%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%85%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5

Comment: @st4rk добавил вариант без ожидания, но в таком случае вы никак не узнаете, выполнилось ли действие успешно или нет.

Comment: @tym32167, спасибо

Comment: @RomanIeromenko, спасибо, прочту

Comment: @RomanIeromenko, т.е я могу запустить сохранение в базу данных просто в отдельном потоке, не прибегая к асинхронному программированию?

Comment: @st4rk поток - это ценный ресурс, асинхронное программирование позволяет не блокировать поток во время операций с БД, но вы да, можете работать с БД синхронно, блокируя отдельный поток, то есть занимая ресурс, который просто будет ждать ответа от БД