# Польза async await в asp.net и при ожидании Task.Delay

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, async-await, асинхронность

У меня есть два вопроса. Я неплохо разобрался в асинхронном программировании в C#, но остались некоторые вопросы.

1) Сейчас я опишу класическую ситуацию в asp.net приложении. К примеру у вас есть Action в контроллере, который возращает какие-нибудь данные (например user'a). В таком случае вы напишите в контроллере обращение к сервису который вернет вам user'a, естественное при вызове этого сервиса вы заюзаете await. Получается когда в репозитории (который вызвается сервисом) произойдет обращение к бд текущий поток освободится и вернется обратно в контроллер где ему тоже ничего не надо делать. Какой в этом смысл? Ну освободил я поток, а дальше то что, пока я не получу данные мои вызывающие методы не могут продолжать работать, так зачем здесь await ? Может в asp.net ограниченное количество потоков которые используются для обработки запросов в моем приложение ? И такое я наблюдаю во всех проектах в куче контор, может я чего то не понимаю?

2) Мы часто используем await перед обращением к бд (запрос в бд где обрабатывается в операционной системе), к файлам компа(тоже операция вне приложения т.е в операционной системе), порой где содаетзся поток уже в приложении. Во всех этих ситуациях что-то выполняет код, пока мои основной поток свободен благодаря await. Я в конец не понимаю зачем все рекомендуют писать await перед Task.Delay. 

   Мы прекрасно знаем что await не создает потоки, а просто дробит метод на куски в зависимости от количества await'ов и продолжает выполнение каждого куска как callback после завершения task'и ну и еще превращает Task в T (все равно что если бы мы использовали ContinueWith). Так кто же тогда выполняет Task.Delay? Может текущий поток (который вызвал Task.Delay), но тогда зачем await? Кто выполняет Task.Delay?

3) В asp.net приложениях, есть такой метод как ConfigureAwait и еще есть такое понятие как HttpContext. ConfigureAwait(false) говорит, что вторая часть после await может выполняться в любом контексте? И как это понимать, у меня будет другой httpcontext что ли? Еще я слышал что в asp.net core это работает как-то по другому и чем же оно там отличается ?

4) И последний вопрос. Асинхронность, это типо когда кусок кода где-то выполняется или чего-то ждет и что бы основной поток не ждал, мы его отпускаем что бы он чем-то другим занялся. А когда кусок кода который нужен был для продолжение заканчивает свои операции мы автоматиечски(ключевое слово автоматически) к нему возвращаемся. Я все правильно понимаю?

Comment: да все так и есть как бы

Comment: @Саске Во 2 и 3 вопросе остается не понятно как оно работает

Comment: У вас много разных вопросов в одном. 1 - число потоков на цпу = число ядер. больше пользователей - больше занято потоков. 2 - любой реально асинхронный запрос освобождает поток, чтобы его можно было переиспользовать. Task.Delay - в том числе. 3 - да. 4 - немного не так. Реальный код выполняется на ЦПУ, а вот какая то асинхронная операция - да, может уйти выполняться не на ЦПУ. После выполнения операции мы вернёмся на ЦПУ автоматом, да.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Нужен async/await или не нужен?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/491632/%d0%9d%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd-async-await-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> текущий поток освободится и вернется обратно в контроллер где ему тоже ничего не надо делать

неверно, текущий поток пойдет обрабатывать другой запрос. Это одна из фишек асинхронности - пока одна задача ждет периферию (БД, файловую систему или сеть), поток может работать над другой задачей.

> Может в asp.net ограниченное количество потоков которые используются для обработки запросов в моем приложение

[Да](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6632413/312041)

> Во всех этих ситуациях что-то выполняет код, пока мои основной поток свободен благодаря await.

Не обязательно свободен, он может выполнять какую то другую работу в это время.

> Я в конец не понимаю зачем все рекомендуют писать await перед Task.Delay.

А что вы перед этим хотите писать? Просто `Task.Delay()` стартует таск, и если вы его не ждете, то этот таск смысла не имеет.

> Мы прекрасно знаем что await не создает потоки, а просто дробит метод на куски

`await` сам по себе ничего не делает, это ключевое слово, оно, в паре с async, переделывает исхожный код в конечный авотмат.

> ConfigureAwait(false) говорит, что вторая часть после await может выполняться в любом контексте?

Да. `ConfigureAwait(false)` означает, что вам наплевать, в каком контексте будет выполнено продолжение. Не рекомендую в таком продолжении пробовать вызывать какие-лобо контекстно зависимые вещи, типа `HttpContext`

> Еще я слышал что в asp.net core это работает как-то по другому и чем же оно там отличается

Был баг, я помню, связанный с дедлоком в asp.net (ссылку не найду наверное), когда вызов `myTask.Result` мог заблочть поток. Это фиксили в asp.net core, в asp.net вроде не фиксили. Но я не работаю с вебом, потому могу ошибаться.

> И последний вопрос.

[Многопоточное vs асинхронное программирование](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/416086/179763)