# Работа windows form

Tags: c#

Есть приложение, в нем обрабатываются большие данные в цикле, если цикл идет достаточно долго то приложение зависает и не обновляется его вид пока метод не завершится. Как сделать это правильно, чтобы программа не виснула?

Comment: запустить обработку отдельным потоком. Например, на пуле потоков.

Comment: использовать асинхронность. запускать данный цикл в отдельном потоке. тогда не будет блокировки интерфейса приложения. Выложи код.

Comment: @tym32167 а использовать асинхронный метод тоже вариант?

Comment: Проще всего какой-нибудь BackgroundWorker использовать, а вообще вариантов много, уже перечислили.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Если вы используете приложение для обработки больших данных из БД,
   то используйте асинхронность
2. Если вам надо делать обработку данных
   только на вашей машине, то используйте параллельные вычисления

[Источник](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/445768/%D0%9C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-vs-%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%85%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)

Также обратите внимание на объем обрабатываемых данных: при использовании больше чем 1 ГБ памяти, рекомендуется использовать x64 сборку