# Что такое асинхронность в программировании?

Tags: любой-язык, асинхронность, event-loop

Не понимаю, почему подход называется асинхронным, если по сути, выполнение этих функций просто переносится в конец синхронной очереди (event loop). Тоже самое, если их просто вызвать последними? Я думал, что это когда параллельно выполняются задачи в одном потоке.

Comment: Синхронный код выполняется строго сверху вниз: Пока одня строчка кода не выполнится, следующая строчка не будет выполнена. Асинхронный код позволяет откладывать выполнение некоторых фрагментов кода, и пока они «ждут», можно продолжать выполнение синхронного кода, не теряя времени. Задачи не выполняются параллельно в одном потоке... Т.е. суть асинхронности: Последовательность строчек кода и последовательность их выполнения не обязательно будет совпадать.

Comment: Поймите простую истину. Асинхронность подразумевает одну вещь. Я вызвал но ответ мне сейчас прям не нужен, когда прийдёт тогда и посмотрим. Тем самым вы не блокируете единственный в случае JavaScript (в многопоточных средах это не так) поток. Это как вы директор и вызвали к себе сотрудника, если ожидать его то это синхронно, а если вызвали и делаете свои дела когда прийдёт тогда и поговорим то это асинхронно

Comment: Вы говорите что "ждет" Ну так я не понимаю, как тогда работает  например js когда файл например обрабатывается, а я паралелльно свободно могу управлять ui???

Answer (score 2):

Стоит объяснить на примере. В одном из обработчиков мы отправили запрос к БД. БД его обрабатывает 5 секунд.

```
app.get('/syncRequestForTest', function(req, res){ // сервер может принять и обработать один запрос в 5 секунд.
    let user = yourDB.users.findSync({_id: req.data.id}) // у нас очень много данных БД, поэтому БД обрабатывает такой запрос 5 секунд. 
    req.send(user)
}
app.get('/other', function(req, res){ // сервер не может обработать этот запрос, пока он занят синхронными вычислениями.
    ...
}
```

В данном примере программа будет ждать синхронный запрос 5 секунд, пока БД вернет ответ. Эти 5 секунд она не может обрабатывать другие запросы, что недопустимо в продакшене.

Если же запрос будет выполняться асинхронно, то во время ожидания ответа от БД сервер сможет обрабатывать другие запросы:

```
app.get('/asyncRequestForTest', async function(req, res){ // сервер может принимать сотни таких запросов в секунду.
    let user = await yourDB.users.findAsync({_id: req.data.id}) // у нас очень много данных БД, поэтому БД обрабатывает такой запрос 5 секунд. 
    req.send(user)
}
app.get('/other', function(req, res){ // сервер может обработать этот запрос, пока где-то снаружи основного потока приложения выполняются асинхронные задачи.
    ...
}
```

Обычно асинхронный подход используется для запросов к сторонним программам (fetch-запрос в браузере, чтение и запись файлов, запросы к БД). Потому что эти запросы обычно длятся сравнительно долго и при этом не загружают ресурсы (все что делает приложение - ждет), а приостанавливать работу всего приложения (например, сервера), пока читается файл для обработки одного из запросов, недопустимо.

Вот [эта статья на английском](https://www.baeldung.com/cs/async-vs-multi-threading) с картинками описывает разницу между синхронным, асинхронным выполнением, а также касается многопоточности.

Вот [статья на Хабре](https://habr.com/ru/post/337528/) с объяснением разницы между этими подходами.

Вот [вопрос на русском StackOverflow](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/445768/%D0%9C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-vs-%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%85%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5), где много хороших примеров по разнице между многопоточностью, асинхронностью, синхронностью и конкуррентностью.

Продублирую здесь ответ:

> Многопоточное программирование подразумевает, что код приложения
> выполняется в разных потоках. Например, есть главный поток UI, и
> несколько рабочих потоков, которые выполняют тяжелые вычисления,
> результаты которых затем выводятся на UI.
>
> Асинхронное программирование подразумевает инициацию некоторой
> операцию, об окончании которой главный поток узнает спустя некоторое
> время. Обычно это применяется для работы с системой ввода-вывода:
> диски, сеть и т.д. При этом, если это все сделано правильно, никакого
> потока нет. Также часто под выражением "выполнить асинхронно"
> подразумевают, что выполнение некоторого кода будет произведено не в
> текущем потоке, а в соседнем, при этом текущий поток не будет
> заблокирован. Но мой взгляд, это не совсем корректно.
>
> Параллельное программирование подразумевает разбиение одной задачи на
> независимые подзадачи, которые можно рассчитать параллельно, а затем
> объединить результаты. Один из примеров -- это map-reduce. Это частный
> случай многопоточного программирования.

Comment: А чем это отличается от многопоточности?

Comment: Многопоточность используется для выполнения тяжелых для процессора задач. Грубо говоря, второй поток - это еще одно синхронное(но не обязательно) приложение.