# асинхронные методы, вопросы

Tags: c#, .net-core, async-await

Доброго время суток братья по цеху)
Есть мучающие меня вопросы) я буду нумеровать чтобы вам легче было отвечать. Потому как их у меня несколько.

Все вопросы будут в рамках следующей задачи. Есть служба, которая запускается в системе и поочередно запускает отдельные процессы (физически отдельные процессы в такс менеджере) и каждый выполняет свою определенную задачу, а по итогу завершается. Я понимаю, что не глядя на реализацию сложно отвечать но хотя бы общие мысли, может быть они уже дадут мне понимание. Ну а я пишу как раз эти плагины/задачи которые потом запускаются в обертке этих процессов.

**И собственно вопросы.**

1. Насколько оправдано применять асинхронные вызовы в рамках одной такой задачи, которая никак не взаимодействует с UI потоком (по сути серверное выполнение). И если оправдано то насколько фанатично их следует использовать? Допустим проверить дни рождения у пользователей или что то подобное. Да там будет основной метод и несколько вспомогательных, возможно даже какой то хелпер класс. Но в любом случае задача не титаническая.
2. Мне попадалось что при серверных выполнениях кода желательно использовать ConfigureAwait(false) чтобы потом лишний раз не синхронизировать потоки, но так же читал что для NET.Сore это не актуально и можно принудительно не дописывать после каждого авэйта.
3. Далее, допустим в рамках похожего как писал выше отдельного процесса в середине мы вызываем какую то длительную асинхронную операцию и пока она выполняется основной поток не блокируется и успешно походит к концу, в то время как асинхронная операция продолжает трудиться. Будет ли условно на последней фигурной скобке основной поток ждать своих авэйтов, когда они все вернуться домой с результатами?) Или обязательно нужно уточнять для него через какой нибудь Task.WhenAll ? И что если это будет ConfigureAwait(false) когда мы с результатом не будем возвращаться в основной поток?
4. Как ведет себя в таких же случаях Parallel.ForEach ? асинхронность работает только внутри тела цикла? пока все потоки Parallel не завершат работу код после цикла не будет выполняться?

Пока только эти вопросы) Заранее спасибо за любые ответы!

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1250885/373567

Answer (score 4):

Ваш вопрос очень широкий и ответ скорее всего породит больше вопросов, чем на что то ответит. Гораздо проще отвечать на конкретнык вопросы, чем на абстрактных коней в вакууме, но я попытаюсь.

1.

> Насколько оправдано применять асинхронные вызовы в рамках одной такой задачи, которая никак не взаимодействует с UI потоком

Если у вас операция ввода вывода, то есть обращение по сети или к файловой системе или в базу данных, и вы не хотите, чтобы поток, клоторый это инициирует, был заблокирован, то используйте асинхронный вызов. Это никак не зависит от того, UI у вас поток или не UI.

2.

> Мне попадалось что при серверных выполнениях кода желательно использовать ConfigureAwait(false)

`ConfigureAwait(false)` означает дословно `мне все равно, в каком потоке будет запущено продолжение`. Если вам все равно, то используйте это.

> но так же читал что для NET.Сore это не актуально

Это неверно. Тут вопрос не в актуальности, а в наличии контекста синхронизации в потоке, который инициирует асинхронную операцию. В старом asp.net контекст синзронизации был, потому `ConfigureAwait(false)` было желательно использовать. В asp.net core контекст синзронизации для потоков-обработчиков запросов выпилили, потому по умолчанию вы можете и не испольовать `ConfigureAwait(false)`, разницы не будет никакой.

3.

> Будет ли условно на последней фигурной скобке основной поток ждать своих авэйтов

Никто никого не ждет.
Если в основном потоке есть контекст синхронизации и продолжения сконфигурированы на него, то когда очередной await отработает, основной поток будет оповещен и продолжит выполнение функции.

```
async Task Foo()
{                       // поток А
    await T1;           
     // продолжение 1   // поток А
    await T2;
     // продолжение 2   // поток А
    await T3;
     // продолжение 3   // поток А
}
```

Если продолжение не привязано к контексту синхронизации, то у вас функция может начаться в одном потоке, а закончится в другом.

```
async Task Foo()
{                       // поток А
    await T1;
     // продолжение 1   // любой поток
    await T2;
     // продолжение 2   // любой поток
    await T3;
     // продолжение 3   // любой поток
}
```

4. 

> Как ведет себя в таких же случаях Parallel.ForEach

Параллельность != асинхронность. Нет смысла запускать 10 потоков, чтобы каждый просто запустил асинхронную операцию и умер. См [Многопоточное vs асинхронное программирование](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/445768/179763)