# В чем разница между асинхронностью, конкурентностью, многопоточностью, многопроцессностью, парралельностью, параллелизмом, корутинами и горутинами?

Tags: многопоточность, асинхронность, терминология

Я знаю разницу между асинхронностью и многопоточностью, многопроцессностью.
Не особо понимаю разницу многопоточностью и многопроцессностью (потоками и процессами)

Потом услышал другие понятия и сошел с ума.

Парралельность и параллелизм это скорее всего одно и тоже.

Я также услышал  слово "корутина" из Java/Kotlin.
А также горутина из Go.

И в чем между всем этим разница? Объясните мне на пальцах, пожалуйста.

Еще бы было желательно с примерами из разных или хотя-бы одного языков/языка

Comment: У потоков внутри одного процесса одна память, они её разделяют между собой; а у процессов память разная, у каждого своя. Корутины - это разновидности то ли потоков, то ли процессов, нужно читать как в конкретном языке это сделано.

Comment: @CrazyElf корутины (горутины, гринлеты и т.д.) - обычно это разделение времени между разными "задачами" в рамках одного потока, они более легковесны, чем потоки или процессы ОС (переключение между ними имеет меньший оверхэд).

Comment: @insolor И это логично, иначе не было бы смысла их делать. Впрочем, на уровне языка могут быть и другие оптимизации, например, "пул потоков".

Comment: @insolor В котлине корутины асинхронные, а в гоу горутины это легковесный поток. В документации написано 
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutines-overview.html, 
https://go.dev/tour/concurrency/1

Comment: Традиционно coroutines (сопрограммы) это логические потоки (псевдопараллельные), которые передают управление друг-другу в определенных точках (yild/resume)

Comment: См. [Многопоточное vs асинхронное программирование](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/445768/)

Answer (score 3):

**Многопроцессорность** - когда у компьютера **несколько процессоров**.

**Многоядерность** - когда у процессора **несколько ядер** (физических и виртуальных)

---

**Параллельность (параллелизм)** - когда задачи выполняются в **одно** время (физически на разных ядрах)

**Конкурентность** - когда задачи работают с **общими** ресурсами.

---

**Асинхронность** - когда несколько задач выполняются одновременно (не обязательно параллельно. Могут выполняться последовательно, но короткими промежутками поочередно)

**Корутина** - механизм (паттерн) позволяющий **асинхронно** выполнять задачи в программировании

**Реализации корутин:**

- C#: Task/async/await
- Go: горутина
- Unity: Coroutine

**Многопоточность** - когда задачи выполняются в разных потоках (threads). Они выполняются асинхронно, т.к. там постоянное переключение между потоками (ядер меньше чем потоков).

По сути это корутина на уровне операционной системы.

Comment: Ты знаешь разницу между процессором и процессом? Я говорил про многопроцеССНОСТЬ.

Comment: Неправильно прочитал. Ни разу не встречал этого термина. Видимо что-то из питона из-за его GIL

Comment: Да это из питона